# Save Layer Styles to a Database

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, style-manager

I would like to save my layer styles to a database and the "only" option given is "As Default in Local Database".  After some searching, I see the local database is named qgis.qmldb under the default profile; However, what if I want to reference my own database or an online database?  Is there a setting to point the "local database" somewhere other than the hard coded path?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to answer my own question.  First I saved the layer to a Spatialite DB.

[image]

Then when I went to the style saving options, my new database connection was one of the options.

[image]